# Before starting php echo a message and activate button?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, load

How do I activate stages of php, for example the user opens the php file. And before starting the script they are asked "are you sure you want to continue". With a button below staying activate.

I have already looked around and I'm sure there is a way to do it but I don't know what it is called. Could someone help me out?

Comment: To be clear: user is clicking on a link or something similar and gets to nextpage.php. Before the content of this file starts to do what it does, you want to ask the user to execute?

Comment: Yes that's what I need sorry only just came back. Have tried your code but it doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: Sorry! Forgot the execute=yeah part...! Updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Short way to do that:

```
if($_GET['execute'] == 'yeah') {
    // your php-file-content goes here....
    // ....
} else {
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?execute=yeah">Are you sure you want to execute this file?</a>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Just put your filecontent between the IF part. It wont be executed untill the request ist yourfilename.php?execute=yeah